# Testing a React component with Enzyme. Typescript can't find instance methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I want to test a React class component.

Let's say I have a method in my class that computes something based on the current state and props.

```
import Component from './Component'

const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Component {...props} />);

it('does something', () => {
  expect(wrapper.instance().someInstanceMethod(input)).toBe(true);
});
```

Typescript says `Property 'someInstanceMethod' is not defined on type Component<any, any>`. How can I tell Typscript how my class is looking and what methods it has?

Is there a good example for this?

Comment: you can always use type assertion:  `(wrapper.instance() as typeof ComponentInstance).someInstanceMethod()`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set the component type in the call to `shallow`. This is a little bit of boilerplate, but it makes things typesafe. The good thing is that the wrapper is typesafe, not just the instance you pull out.

```
import Component from './Component'

// Wrapper will know the type of the component.
const wrapper = enzyme.shallow<Component>(<Component {...props} />);

it('does something', () => {
  expect(wrapper.instance().someInstanceMethod(input)).toBe(true);
  // You can also get the state from the wrapper.
  expect(wrapper.state().someComponentState).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 26):

One possible solution (thanks to the comment from marzelin) is to explicitly declare the type of the `instance()` method. There might be more elegant ways to do this.

```
import Component from './Component'

const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Component {...props} />);
const instance = wrapper.instance() as Component; // explicitly declare type

it('does something', () => {
  expect(instance.someInstanceMethod(input)).toBe(true); // no TS error
});
```

Comment: what happens if function is private?  ts has an error: Property 'someInstanceMethod' is private and only accessible within class 'Component'.

Comment: @jhonnylopez ive got the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: This worked. But I am curious as to why it cannot figure it out... Just cost me hours of my day.

Comment: I get : "Component refers to a value but is used as a type here"

Comment: @Sytham Can you try changing your file extension to `.tsx`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @marzelin and @Chris!
Other possible solution

```
import Component from './Component'

const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Component {...props} />);
const instance = wrapper.instance() as any; // explicitly declare type

it('does something', () => {
  expect(instance.someInstanceMethod(input)).toBe(true); // no TS error
});
```

This comes in handy where `someInstanceMethod` receives event as parameter, explicitly declare type as `component` requires you to pass whole event object which is not something a developer want for writing test cases.