# Typescript: Type of a React component cannot be found in a test file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

What I've been trying is to test a react component with Jest (Enzyme) in a `.tsx` file (i.e. Typescript), following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625581/testing-a-react-component-with-enzyme-typescript-cant-find-instance-methods) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830165/how-to-mock-react-component-methods-with-jest-and-enzyme).

Here is a snippet of my code.

(**EDIT**: Thank you @WillJenkins! I updated this snippet after I read your advice)

```
describe('MyComponent', ()=>{
  const mockStore = createMockStore([thunk]);
  let store = mockStore({});      

  it('should render ChildComponent if getFoo is true', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <MyComponent />
        </Provider>
    );

    let instance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance() as MyComponent;
    // "MyComponent" shows a warning message,
    // saying "Cannot find name 'MyComponent'."

    instance().getFoo = jest.fn();
    instance().getFoo.mockImplementation(() => true);

    instance.update();

    expect(instance.contains(<ChildComponent />)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

For some reason, `MyComponent` after the `as` keyword can't be found when I use it as the type of `wrapper.instance()`.

If I hover over it, it says "`Cannot find name 'MyComponent'.`"

(Strangely, `MyComponent` within `find()`) doesn't give any warning)

If I replace

`let instance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance() as MyComponent;`

with

`wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance().getFoo = jest.fn()`

..., it results in a different warning message, saying that `"Property 'getFoo' does not exist on type 'Component<any, any, any>'"`

If I put `any` instead of `MyComponent`, it doesn't show any warning but the test itself results in an type error (`instance.update() is not a function`)

What is the correct type for `instance()`? I can't find any clue in Jest and Enzyme's doc.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: are you importing the component from the `.jsx` file like in the example: `import Component from './Component'` at the top of your test file? in your case it would be `import MyComponent from './MyComponent'` where `./MyComponent` should be a relative path to your `MyComponent.jsx` file (don't include the extension on the import)

Comment: @PedroMaiaCosta, this component is imported as `import { MyComponent } from '../MyComponent'`. I'm sure that the path is correct, because changing it to anything else will give a warning message, which is caused by TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper isn't a `<MyComponent>`, it's a `<Provider>`.

You need to use [find](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) to locate your `MyComponent` in your mounted tree:

```
let instance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, however, using the line (`let instance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance()`) didn't solve the issue. TypeScript is now complaining that `Property 'getFoo' does not exist on type 'Component<any, any, any>'` just after the line.